# unresolved external symbol, ATIDAQ, VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

I'm extremely confused and have been going in circles for about the past hour with this now.

I am attempting to add the [ATIDAQ C Library](http://www.ati-ia.com/Products/ft/software/daq_software.aspx) to my project [zip link here for the ATIDAQ C Library](http://www.ati-ia.com/library/software/daq_ft/ATIDAQ%20C%20Library.zip). In my project I have added:

```
C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories: <PATH_TO_LIB>\ATIDAQ C Library\ATIDAQ
```

However I keep getting the error `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _createCalibration`

#### main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
#include <ftconfig.h>
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *calfilepath;      // name of calibration file
  unsigned short index;   // index of calibration in file (second parameter; default = 1)
  Calibration *cal = NULL;      // struct containing calibration information
  unsigned short i, j;     // loop variables

  index = 1;
  calfilepath = argv[1];
  cal = createCalibration(calfilepath, index);
  printf("                  Serial: %s\n", cal->Serial);
  printf("              Body Style: %s\n", cal->BodyStyle);
}
```

Which is I think caused by the line     `C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories: <PATH_TO_LIB>\ATIDAQ C Library\ATIDAQ`. The IDE finds the `Calibration *createCalibration(char *CalFilePath, unsigned short index);` function (as this is not syntax highlighted and tab completes).

I'm really unsure what is going, wrong. I think I am missing something with the linker, but I am just not sure as to what.

Answer (score 0):

The ATIDAQ C Library doesn't provide a .lib for you to link against; instead, you should instruct the Visual C++ compiler to compile the necessary C source files in the same folder. In this case, `createCalibration` is implemented in ftconfig.c.